# jquery add remove class onclick

Tags: jquery, navigation, addclass, removeclass

i have any navigation menu !

```
   <div class="nav">
    <ul class="navigation">
    <li class="selected"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PROFILE></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACTUS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOATUS</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Now how to add selected class after click to any ( profile, Contactus, aboutus ) and remove selected home using Jquery.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On the assumption that you want to have only *one* element of class-name `selected` I suggest:

```
$('ul.navigation li a').click(
    function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action
        e.stopPropagation(); // stop the click from bubbling
        $(this).closest('ul').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eMx7X/).

Comment: Sorry, can you explain what you mean by `e.stopPropagation()` bubbling up the dom tree? Is it in case the surrounding wrappers are attached to click events?

Answer (score 8):

you can use toggleClass:

```
$("#myElement1").click(function(){
   $("#myElement2").toggleClass("myClass");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$("a").click(function()
{
  $("a").parent().removeClass("selected");

  $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/35QaP/)

Comment: Thanks i tested this, This Worked For Which ID , Class Or All a link